# how to lock an Access table file after a period (linked tables)

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an  Access database file with tables linked with an Access database executive file, my question is: How can I prevent users from dealing with this file after a period of time, I mean from the tables file and not the executable file.
That is, I want a code to put it inside the tables file and not inside the executable file so that after a period of time the tables file will be locked and become unusable.

for example:
Can I set a password for the tables' Access file after a period of time ??

is there any method can I apply by VBA or anything else??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Access/VBA.

But, as the shared database will be on a network share, use a network server where you programmatically can lock out users.

Comment: is there any method to rename the tables?

Comment: Yes, but that can't be done while the tables are open.